# How can I deliver goods to towns?

Tags: openttd

I have a problem transporting the goods from the factory to the town.  I order the truck to go to the truck station after collecting all the goods from the factory but nothing happens.

Comment: Does the town accept goods?  If you click on the station it should say what it wants/can provide.

Answer (score 16):

The station has to accept goods:

[image]

To do that it has to have enough ***commercial*** town buildings ***within its catchment area*** (it doesn't matter that the whole town has enough, the individual buildings must be near the station!) to generate a full demand of goods.

This *Small Office Building*, for example, only provides one eighth of a goods need.
[image]

While this *Highrise Commercial* building provides one half (four eighths).
[image]

There has to be enough buildings of this nature *within a station's catchment area* for the total goods demand to be ***at least one whole***.

These buildings appear much more frequently in larger towns and cities, and tend to be clustered near the centre of the town - and again, your station must have them within it's catchment area for this to work.

Comment: It's risky to build an individual station this way in medium/smaller towns because it's very, very likely that your Goods-needing building will be replaced with something else as the town grows. (The growth will make a more permanent need more likely, though)

Comment: good to know the exact breakdown of commercial buildings/goods

Answer (score 3):

The receiving station must first accept goods.  Not all town accepts goods until they are of sufficient population, and your station typically must be in a good location.  Being in the fringes of a town is usually not enough for a station to accept goods, try placing a station closer to the 'downtown' area.

Comment: Ensure you use the station catchment area toggle, and watch the 'accepted cargo' as you move the blueprint around town.

Comment: You can also glue a truck depot to a large airport, which has a much larger spread. Using one of them to cover a majority of a town will usually get you close to accepting Goods, and definitely will if you do it at a large town/city.